# Define a dynamic controller in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a directive that has a dynamic template, now I want the directive to have the ability to use different controllers.  Is it possible to dynamically assign a controller to a directive?  If possible, would that be the same "ctrlr" then passed to the `link` function?

```
.directive('myDirective',['$compile',function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: function(el,attrs){
            return (angular.isDefined(attrs.template)) ? attrs.template : '/tmpls/default';
        },
        link : function(scope,el,attrs,ctrlr,transFn){
            [... Do Stuff Here ...]
        },
        controller: [ DYNAMIC CONTROLLER ASSIGNMENT?? ]
    };
}]);
```

Comment: By dynamic do you mean pull down an ambient controller (through `require`) or allow the controller to be set directly on the directive?

Comment: @DavinTryon I thought about using `require` but it won't work for my the situation I'm thinking of, it would mean encapsulating X amount of controllers in X amount of directives to associate with the directive I have in mind.  I need to be able to set the controller directly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While I didn't find the corresponding documentation for it in the official API, you can dynamically pass in the name of the controller you want to use by utilizing the "name" attribute in conjunction with providing the "controller" attribute with a value that uses the similar syntax you'd use for an isolate scope.

Using your sample code, assuming a controller called "myController":

HTML:

```
<my-directive ctrlr="myController"></my-directive>
```

JS:

```
.directive('myDirective',['$compile',function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: function(el,attrs){
            return (angular.isDefined(attrs.template)) ? attrs.template : '/tmpls/default';
        },
        link : function(scope,el,attrs,ctrlr,transFn){
            [... Do Stuff Here ...]
        },
        controller: '@',
        name: 'ctrlr'
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I'll try it but I don't think that was a possible property in the version of Angular at the time I wrote this question.

Comment: @m.e.conroy It's not a new thing... it was in the version that was current back in December. Which version were you using? Like I said, it's not documented, the property is available in the source -- and some courses teach the use of it. Wish I would have seen your question sooner. Hard to pick out the good questions, like this one, through the noise. :)

Comment: @m.e.conroy, did you use (try) this yet?

Comment: I ended up reformulating the application I was working on such that I didn't need to have dynamic controllers for my directives, been so busy that I haven't had a chance to test this solution.  I'll give you the check and test it when I can.

Comment: @RobM if i could give you +1000 i would! It makes me feel weird that such a useful feature isn't documented. Like i'm doing something wrong. But it works a treat! Thanks

Comment: @james Glad you found the solution useful! :) In the right situation it can be incredibly useful. Like you, I was also surprised that it isn't documented. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @RobM What if "ctrlr" attributte has a variable? like this: <my-directive ctrlr="{{myController}}"></my-directive>? this isn't working

Answer (score -2):

This is how it is done:

Inside your directive element all you need is an attribute which gives you access to the name of the controller:

```
<card-dealer ng-repeat="card in cards" card="card"></card-dealer>
```

in my case my **card** attribute holds a card object which has a **name** property.

In the directive you set the isolate scope to:

```
scope: { card: '=' }
```

This isolates and interpolates the card object to the directive scope. You then set the directive template to:

```
template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
```

this looks to the directive's controller for a function named getTemplateUrl and allows you to set the templateUrl dynamically as well.

In the directive controller the getTemplateUrl function looks like this:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
  $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () { 
    return '/View/Card?cardName=' + $scope.card.name;
  };
}]
```

I have an mvc controller which links up the proper .cshtml file and handles security when this route is hit, but this would work with a regular angular route as well.

In the .cshtml/html file you set up your dynamic controller by simply putting

`<div ng-controller="CardContactController"></div>`

as the root element. The controller will differ for each template. This creates a hierarchy of controllers which allows you to apply additional logic to all cards in general, and then specific logic to each individual card. I still have to figure out how I'm going to handle my services but this approach allows you to create a dynamic templateUrl and dynamic controller for a directive using an ng-repeat based on the controller name alone. It is a very clean way of accomplishing this functionality and it is all self-contained.